# Different handlers for ejb Timer

Tags: ejb, quartz-scheduler, timertask

I'm trying to set different handlers for different types of tasks created via TimerService , ejb.

I need to figure out a way where I can create a schedule tasks with extra information including the handler type so when a timeout occurs different handlers should be fired according to the timer identification.

Comment: Is the schedule intended to be user modifiable at runtime? Also it's unclear if you're looking at Quartz scheduling or the EJB timer service. They are two different technologies than happen to be able to provide similar services.

Comment: Yes , I think I have found the answer. I have used the approach of using the TimerConfig wehn adding a Timer  object to have a serialized handler so in a timeout I can get the actual handler from that Timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the solution to the problem as i tried to explain is by adding Serialized handler, which is set when you create a timer event.

after you set a handler you can get it from the timer object, so when a timeout occurs we can execute an action according to the relevant handler.